# PHP x time passed hide mysql value

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to see if the value is over the current time, multiply by st-ads-time 3600 number as in the picture, how can I do this?

[image: tinypic]

My Code:

```
<?php
$advertisement_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM andesite_advertisement ORDER BY advertisement_id DESC");
$num_log = mysql_num_rows($advertisement_query);
if ($num_log > 0) {
    while ($ads_row = mysql_fetch_array($advertisement_query)) {
        $ads_ase = $ads_row['advertisement_base'];
        $is_buyed_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM andesite_adsrice WHERE adsrice_adsase = '$ads_ase' AND adsrice_username = '$user_nickname'");
        while ($is_row = mysql_fetch_array($is_buyed_query)) {
            $timeA = $is_row['adsrice_time'];
            $timeB = date("d.m.Y H:i");
            $timeDiff = strtotime($timeB) - strtotime($timeA);
            if ($timeDiff > $ads_time) {
                echo '
                    <tr id="'.$ads_row['advertisement_base'].'">
                        <td>'.$ads_row['advertisement_id'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$ads_row['advertisement_title'].'</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-success flat btn-xs" href="Surf/'.$ads_row['advertisement_base'].'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;'.ls_view.'</a></td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.ls_nothata.'</td>
            <td>'.ls_nothata.'</td>
            <td>'.ls_nothata.'</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query shows only those ads which have a matching `advertisement_base` and only when the current time is after their `adsrise_time` but before `adsrise_time` plus `st-ads-time` hours.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM andesite_advertisement ORDER BY advertisement_id DESC";
$advertisement_query = mysql_query($query);
$num_log = mysql_num_rows($advertisement_query);
if ($num_log > 0) 
{
    while ($ads_row = mysql_fetch_array($advertisement_query)) 
    {
        $ads_ase = $ads_row['advertisement_base'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM andesite_adsrice 
          WHERE adsrice_adsase = '$ads_ase' 
            AND adsrice_username = '$user_nickname' 
            AND NOW() BETWEEN adsrise_time AND ADDTIME(adsrise_time, INTERVAL 
              (SELECT setting_value 
                FROM settings 
                WHERE setting_name = 'st-ads-time'
              ))";
        $is_buyed_query = mysql_query($query);
        while ($is_row = mysql_fetch_array($is_buyed_query)) 
        {
            echo '<tr id="'.$ads_row['advertisement_base'].'">
                  <td>'.$ads_row['advertisement_id'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$ads_row['advertisement_title'].'</td>
                  <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-success flat btn-xs" href="Surf/' . $ads_row['advertisement_base'] . '" target="_blank">
                      <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;'.ls_view.'
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>';
            }
        }
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.ls_nothata.'</td>
            <td>'.ls_nothata.'</td>
            <td>'.ls_nothata.'</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

Comment: How can `DELETE` be the answer to this question?

Comment: no, if the problem adsrice_adsase is equal to advertisement_base, show when the specified time has passed. Example: st-ads-time value 6, ie 6 hours after strtotime, but it does not work.

Comment: Multilingual features are also available if the software is available. With skype I will send you the file.

Comment: It seems that I have misunderstood your question. I though that you want to show only those ads whose deadline has not passed yet. Your last comment makes me think that you want the opposite - showing only those ads whose deadline has already passed.

Comment: Updated the answer.